# Mixing prototypes with singletons

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I've got some application in Spring, which on every request creates prototype bean X (from factory). This bean X has some DAO singletons e.g. Y, Z. and SomeObject on which I work (set values etc.)

```
@Scope(value="prototype")
public class X{
   @Autowired 
   private Y y;
   @Autowired
   private Z z;

   private SomeObject obj;

   public void someMethod(){
   obj.setProperty();
   }
}
```

Is it right approach? I mean, in every request Spring container must search for those singleton beans and inject them into prototype, is it effective? Or maybe it's better to create stateless bean and create SomeObject instance in appropriate method, and then pass it in function arguments whenever I want to use it (it's not so comfortable)?

Comment: I assume `someMethod()` will effectively use `y` and `z`? (can you correct the code: `X` should be `Y` in the class).

Comment: Yes, someMethod() effectively use y and z to produce some data for obj. Corrected.

Comment: But is `SomeObject` just internal state of `X`, that holds some state between various call to different methods of `X`, or is it visible from outside of `X`?

Comment: Yes, it's visible from outside. X is prototype bean with state.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use singleton scope and stateless beans because stateless beans are thread-safe. Use statefull beans only if you can not use stateless.

Comment: Yup, I know, but in every book from "Clean code" series there is mentioned to use instance variables as much as possible, because it makes code more readable and there is no need to pass object in every method when it needs to be change(e.g. what if we have 10 methods? In every method we must have SomeObject variable in method definition). It makes sping beans really awful to read but for sure thread-safe,

Comment: All rules have a scope =) Instance variables are a good solution for classes with complex logic. But services (or other building blocks like data access objects) should be stateless. You can combine this rules and use instance variables in non-spring helper class and then create local variable instance of this class in singleton service.